# How to cyclically Kronecker multiply matrices of dimension 2 to result in a matrix 2^N

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matrix

I need to perform a Kronecker product between different matrices of dimension `(2,2)`. The problem is that I have to cycle the sigma matrix in the `i-th` position and then add each multiplied term up like in the following formula [here](https://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%5Cdpi%7B120%7D%20%5Clarge%20%5Csigma%5Cotimes%20I%5Cotimes%20I%20%5Cotimes%20I%20+%20I%20%5Cotimes%20%5Csigma%20%5Cotimes%20I%20%5Cotimes%20I%20+%20I%20%5Cotimes%20I%20%5Cotimes%20%5Csigma%20%5Cotimes%20I%20+%20I%20%5Cotimes%20I%20%5Cotimes%20I%20%5Cotimes%20%5Csigma).

This is what I tried so far, but I'm missing something. I think it's not necessary to use a list of arrays but it's the only idea that came to me.

If `N=4` then the output matrix should be of dimension `(16,16)` with non-null elements only on the diagonal.

The output of the first term in the formula should be:

```
items_1 = [s_z, s_0, s_0, s_0]

r = items_1[0]

for i in items_1[1:4]:
    r = kron(r, i)
    
print(diag(r))

Output [ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
```

But then I have to write the second element with another for-loop and so on and so forth. I should write for loops for each elements in the sum. Something that is against the main goal: find a procedure to that gives the total matrix as an output for an arbitrary 2^N.

By the way the solution I found is written in [this](https://juliaphysics.github.io/PhysicsTutorials.jl/tutorials/general/quantum_ising/quantum_ising.html) article but I cannot translate it in python.

```
from numpy import *
from numba import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import *
import itertools

# First, let's define the needed pauli matrices for the problem

s_0 = array([[1,0],
             [0,1]])

s_x = array([[0,1],
             [1,0]])

s_z = array([[1,0],
             [0,-1]])

items = [s_0, s_x, s_z]

items_1 = [s_z, s_0, s_0, s_0]

list_cycle = itertools.cycle(items_1)
next(list_cycle)

sum_= 0
r = items_1[0]
for j in items_1:
    for i in items_1[1:4]:
        r = kron(r, i)
    sum_ += r
    items_1 = next(list_cycle)
    
print(r.shape)
```

The output I get here:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-5f4f71d5edc8> in <module>
      7     for i in items_1[1:4]:
      8         r = kron(r, i)
----> 9     sum_ += r
     10     items_1 = next(list_cycle)
     11 

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (16,16) (16,32) (16,16)
```

`sum_` should output the sum of the cyclic Kronecker product.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Useless to say that it throws out just errors and now I'm stuck. Any help would be much appreciated." Then please try to say something useful instead. We [cannot simply "help you"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). What actually goes wrong? [Exactly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) what is the error, and what happened [when you tried to narrow down the cause](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? Do individual parts of the code seem to do what they should?

Comment: At the `sum_ += r` line of code, exactly what do you expect `r` to look like? In particular, what should its type be? If it should be some kind of matrix, what should the dimensions be? Therefore, what should `sum_` look like, in order to make that work out? Therefore, what should the initial value be?

Comment: Ehi, Karl thank you for the response. I'll try to edit as you suggested.